# Is the Firestore transaction ID unique irregardless of case?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We are using a firestore and then using the auto generated ID with another integration.  In the integration response, the responder is changing the firestore ID to all uppercase.

Do we know if the auto generated IDs are guaranteed to be unique regardless of case or is there a chance to have collision with different strings of same characters but different cases?

Tried researching this in the fire store documentation but didn't see a defnitive answer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generated IDs that you can get from Firestore are statistically guaranteed to be unique. This essentially means that the value is so random that chances of two clients generating the same ID is *really* small. So small in fact that we all agreed to treat them as unique.

The reason the chance of duplicates is so small is because the auto-generated IDs are both long and consist if a wide range of characters.

Since the remote system you call converts all characters to uppercase, it reduces the amount of randomness (usually called entropy) in the key - almost halving it.

There is no guarantee that Firestore will never generate that modify key, but then again... there was no guarantee of that to begin with. The chances were just really small, and the translation the remote system did doubled those chances.

You will have to decide for yourself whether that doubled chance acceptable. If it isn't, you can use some lossless encoding for the ID. That'll make the key longer to compensate for the fact that there are fewer unique characters to choose from.